# MySQL Удалить строку по максимальному значению

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть запрос:

```
delete from `shtat` order by `zp` desc limit 1;
```

При выполнении выдает ошибку:

> Error Code: 1451. Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`employees`.`depart`, CONSTRAINT `depart_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`id`) REFERENCES `shtat` (`otdel`))

Не могу понять куда копать.

Comment: в ограничения. посмотрите код вот этого Constraint depart_ibfk_1, вы должны понять, в чем проблема

Answer (score 0):

1451 имеет 2 возможные причины:

1. Изменение данных в родительской таблице. Если в определении внешнего ключа не задано действие при update/delete, то такие операции над родительской таблицей могут привести к несогласованности данных, т.е. появлению в дочерней таблице записей не имеющих соответствия в родительской таблице.
2. Не уникальный ключ в родительской таблице. По стандарту SQL набор полей, на которые ссылается внешний ключ, должен быть уникальным. Однако, реализация внешних ключей в InnoDB позволяет иметь несколько "родителей". Из-за этого возникает трудно диагностируемая ошибка.

Источник - https://sqlinfo.ru/articles/info/30.html